Basis of Specht module of symmetric groups
I am reading the construction of the Specht module from James's book. The Specht module of a symmetric group corresponding to a partition $\lambda$ is spanned by all polytabloids $e_{t}$ associated with a tableau $t$ of shape $\lambda$.
There is an another description for the Specht module of symmetric group in Chapter 3, Section 2 of [A. Mathas,  Iwahori–Hecke algebras and Schur algebras of the symmetric group, University Lecture Series, 15, Amer. Math. Soc., Providence, RI, 1999; MR1711316].
I would like to understand how the bases are equivalent.

Disclaimer : I have never fully understand the approach of Jucys-Murphy elements. But my understanding is the following : in James' book, we construct Specht modules having a basis in standard tableaux, and we derive the branching rule from them ; whereas in the other approach, we construct a basis using the branching rule, and show that it corresponds to standard tableaux. The following notes make links between these two approachs : https://pi.math.cornell.edu/~dmehrle/notes/partiii/reptheory_partiii_notes.pdf.

Could you give a summary of the construction from Mathas's book?

By Proposition 3.22 of Mathas's book, the Specht module $S^{\lambda}$ is generated as a free module with the basis ${m_{t}: t \text{ is a standard tableau of shape } \lambda}$. This is coming from the cell basis of a symmetric group. So, my question is how $m_t$ is related with $e_t$.

If it is coming from the cell basis, then he gives you a rule to write $\sigma \cdot m_t$ ($\sigma \in \mathfrak{S}n$) in the given basis. It which should be equivalent to the rule used to write $\sigma \cdot e_t = e{\sigma \cdot t}$ in the standard basis. The latter is given by Garnir elements, so you should see if Mathas' construction is equivalent to them.
